# integration throws error in android using react-native-papal

Tags: paypal, react-native

I used the module react-native-paypal, But while integrating in Android, it throws some error during the running of Android, here is the screenshot of the error .
[image]

Here is the code where it shows error
**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.camp;

    import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
    import android.content.Intent; // <--


    public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
        //public static Activity activity;
    //private static final int PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID = 9
        /**
         * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
         * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
         */

        @Override
       public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

           if (requestCode == 9) {
                payPalPackage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // <--
            } else {
                otherModulesHandlers(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String getMainComponentName() {
            return "Camp";
        }

    }
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.camp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import br.com.vizir.rn.paypal.PayPalPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
   private static final int PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID = 9; // <-- Can be any unique number
    private PayPalPackage payPalPackage; // <--

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      payPalPackage = new PayPalPackage(PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID);  // <--
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        payPalPackage,  // <--
          new MainReactPackage()

      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

Please give me suggestions on how to resolve this error. Any help is much appreciated

After all changes in my code, But still facing some problem please see the below image
[image]

please give me suggestions that how to solve these type of errors

**paypalcode in react-native**

```
paypal(){
    PayPalAndroid.paymentRequest({
      clientId: '............',
      environment: PayPalAndroid.SANDBOX,
      price: '0.01',
      currency: 'EUR',
      description: 'PayPal Test'
    }).then((confirm, payment) => console.log('Paid'))
    .catch((error_code) => console.error('Failed to pay through PayPal'));
  }
```

here instead of console i wrote alert but  it doen't show alert, i tried for many times, i didn't get success alert or catch alert, Please give me suggestions that how to resolve it

Comment: Can you add your java code?

Comment: @agent_hunt added the java code please check it and give me suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The react-native-paypal version on npm registry and its repository hasn't been updated to work latest react-native versions. You can use this fork  https://github.com/sharafat/react-native-paypal instead.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.38.0",
    "react-native-paypal": "https://github.com/sharafat/react-native-paypal.git"
  },
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...    
import android.content.Intent;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ReactNativePayPalTest";
    }

    @Override
 public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MainApplication.PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID) { // <--
        ((MainApplication) getApplication()).payPalPackage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // <--
    } else {
//        otherModulesHandlers(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
 }
}
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
...

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.vizir.rn.paypal.PayPalPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  public static final int PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID = 9; // <-- Can be any unique number
  public PayPalPackage payPalPackage;

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      payPalPackage = new PayPalPackage(PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID);
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          payPalPackage
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Comment: above screenshot is the error which i am facing after all changes in my code please give me suggestions that how to solve this

Comment: You are probably using older react-native code. Make sure you are importing Component from react package something  like this `import React, { Component } from 'react';` instead of `import React, { Component } from 'react-native';`

Comment: i am doing like that only but the error is in module code react-native-paypal index.js code please give me suggestions

Comment: payPalPackage = new PayPalPackage(PAY_PAL_REQUEST_ID); basically the error is like this in terminal

Comment: Haven't you changed your package.json file as shown in the answer ? Make sure to npm install

Comment: same problem but the problem is now not with paypalPackage it is as like above screenshot please give me suggestion that how to resolve

Comment: i added my react-native code here i want to show the success message in alert but it is not showing the alert of success or failure

Comment: Will Any body provide working code? getting same issue as in first screen! @HussianShaik did you fixed it?